# Smooth fonts with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, antialiasing

How can I get smooth fonts? I don't want the edges to look all fuzzy.

*Hacky solutions are not a problem :)*

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think CSS3 has a `font-smooth:always;` property. I have yet to try it myself, so I cant comment on its effectiveness.

Comment: Have a look here (same topic): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/font-smoothing/11493510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some font replacement solution like [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) for headers, but it's too inefficient to use for large blocks of text.

If you're looking to change the browser's font rendering, you probably won't have much luck because they all have their own text rendering routines (but look at `-webkit-font-smoothing` for recent versions of Safari and Chrome).

Comment: Well it would probably only be needed for things with a large font size so big blocks of text wont be a problem. Why is Cufon so in efficient?

Comment: It's not particularly inefficient, it's just that using a browser's native text rendering routines will always be faster than using a custom JavaScript library that uses Canvas or SVG to display text.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned, there is a CSS property for `font-smooth` - but I am not sure how widely this is supported. This is most likely a property that you will have to adjust in your OS, or the font itself, which means of course, that would only be local. I know that Windows has a feature called [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx) which allows you to adjust the anti-aliasing to work well with your monitor.

As Ben Alpert mentioned, a font-replacement solution such as [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) or [TypeKit](http://typekit.com/) are other potential solutions for title text.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a CSS property called text-rendering which actually works on the Firefox family of browsers. There's also -webkit-font-smoothing for Safari and Chrome family, as Ben said. I don't know if text-rendering works on Internet Explorer, but this piece of code works pretty fine:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Also, if you're customizing your browser:

```
html {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
```