# how to make my HTML 'font' edge color match with background on css?

Tags: html, css

how to make my HTML 'font' edge match with background on css ?

i meant to make the color of a 'fat font'(font size) change pixel by pixel to match the background.

such as white font n black background. how to make the font edge color smoothly / gradually change match to background?

e.g.

```
<div style="font-size: 24px; weight: 600; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

MY TITLE n LOGO

</div>
```

obviously this can do in photoshop as image, but that would break-my-rule-of-bandwidth. i want it to be HTML n CSS purely. IT IS POSSIBLE? is there any relationship to 'anti-aliasing' thing ? what is anti-alias actually? lazy mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to do (a bit unclear question) is to **cast a blurring shadow** to the text **that has no offset**. You can do that by applying a CSS style to your text using `text-shadow` property like so:

```
{text-shadow:0 0 2px #888;}
```

or in your case:

```
<div style='font-size: 24px; 
            weight: 600; 
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            text-shadow:0 0 2px #888;'>
</div>
```

**> [Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Cmss/) for it.**

---

You can find a reference for this `Text-Shadow` CSS property at **[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp)**. It takes four parameters:

- ***`h-shadow`**: Required. The position of the horizontal shadow. Negative values are allowed*
- ***`v-shadow`**: Required. The position of the vertical shadow. Negative values are allowed*
- ***`blur`**:     Optional. The blur distance*
- ***`color`**:    Optional. The color of the shadow.*

---

***Note that this property isn't supported in Internet Explorer browsers lower than IE10.***

What you could do though for IE browsers is apply a blurring filter to the text:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=1);
```

or a glowing filter:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=gray,Strength=1);
```

or both:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=1)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=gray,Strength=1);
```

IE static filters reference can be found at **[http://msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms673539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).**

Comment: thanks. that shadow help a lot, at least, temporarily. but i think the antialiasing for 'font-smooth' property is the one. but it seems i still couldn't manage to make it happen in <div> or <p> tag. might be working for some other <tag>.

Comment: What you call 'Anti-aliasing' and is better known as `font smoothing` isn't something you can control through HTML/CSS/JS as it's system dependent. You can turn it off in IE with a trick to apply `filter: alpha(opacity=XX)` with a value of less than 100 (say 99 would do it).  If your system has it turned on and you don't see it in your browser, then either you're using a browser that doesn't support it (some Safari versions didn't, for example), or you're using `alpha opacity` on parent elements and that trick I mentioned applies to children elements as well in IE browsers.

Comment: You can read more on limitations of `font smoothing` in various browsers and advantages to the blurred shadow technique **[here](http://daneden.me/2010/12/css-font-smoothing/)** and a SO discussion about it **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/font-smoothing)**.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your like this

```
<div style='font-size: 24px; weight: 600; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>
```

Comment: ya sorry. accidentally slipped