# Bad font rendering - what are the causes, what the workarounds?

Tags: css, browser, fonts, cross-browser

I am building a website which makes intensive use of the **Bebas Neue** typeface. As I often do, I let [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to the dirty job for me and I downloaded the pre-build `@font-face` directly from the Bebas Neue [page](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bebas-neue).

I imported the downloaded stylesheet + fonts directly in my website. What I got is very bad font rendering in such big browsers as Chrome and Firefox.
Here's a bunch of screenshots:

Chrome (pretty bad):
[image: pretty bad font rendering in Chrome]

Firefox (horrible, my lord have mercy):
[image: horrible font rendering in Firefox]

Opera (very decent, that's what I want *everywhere*):
[image: actually terrific font rendering in Opera (yay)]

Safari (perfect):
[image: decent font rendering in Safari]

I didn't specify any font rendering or anti-alias options in my CSS; on the other hand, I use `normalize.css`.

What could be the cause of such a horrible rendering?

**Note**: I already posted too many pics for a single question, but I'm using the [Grand Hotel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/grand-hotel) font too and God, it's even worse (but each browser behaves consistently, at least).

Comment: Now try it on Windows.

Comment: I'm not able to, I only have Macs :( **And** no VMs actually, but that's on the to-do list.

Comment: It's bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/is-there-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome-because-webfonts-look-very-edgy

Comment: Ok, in Chrome it's a bug, but what about Firefox? It's terrible there.

Comment: Each browser/OS combination can have its own way of rendering fonts. If you absolutely must have the same appearance everywhere, the only option is to use an image (but for accessibility you'll need to do some tricks like invisible text over the top) or a plugin (Flash gives you one option for consistent font rendering, though I would strongly discourage you from following that path). You can try using CSS3's text-rendering property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering) but it's not well supported.

Comment: My mistake, it's not CSS3 but rather a mozilla-specific extension of the SVG spec, hence not being generally supported. But it should help your FireFox issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on my font.
I fixed the problem for the bold style with that less mixin applied on my bold style elements:

```
.font-smoothing {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```