# Font-Face Issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, font-face, render

I have a problem with DinProRegular font. "t" character looks like "l". Only Chrome having this problem. [image]

What is the problem?

http://prj.disual.net/beybi/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=291&Itemid=265

Comment: That's common Chrome problem. Check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/is-there-any-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Chrome. The best work around that I found is that if you hide and re-show the content of the body the font will load properly
Hope this helps

```
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    font-family: folio_medium;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```