# How to make web fonts smoother in all browser

Tags: css, webfonts

I have used josefinsans webfont but the font is not looking smoother.It is looking rough and pixelated in all browsers.

I have tried by using both google web font as well as web font generated by using font generator and implemented it with @font-face.

Refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbL92/5/)

Html:

```
<div>
    <p>Coming Soon</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
body{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:48px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px 1px;` ,
You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11493510/1427849) !
And this is [How To Properly Smooth Font Using CSS3](http://www.icondeposit.com/blog:how-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3) !

Comment: Its not supporting and also its looking odd if we used text-shadow.