# Is there any reason not to use font-smoothing: antialiased?

Tags: css, browser, fonts

Is there any reason not to use `font-smoothing: antialiased`?

Comment: Too subjective IMO. Quick google search yields: http://madebynico.com/webkit-font-smoothing/

Comment: For firefox use `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;` to fix OSX's dodgy font rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not all typefaces are optimized for alternative smoothing modes
- Browser support is incredibly spotty, in fact I believe it's actually a proprietary WebKit property, i.e. `-webkit-font-smoothing`, and not in any standard (the only "standard" I am aware of is `font-smooth` which was never relevant anyway)

That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Font-smoothing is not supported now.
It is not in new css standards.
http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth

From : [Is there any "font smoothing" in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/is-there-any-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome/11493510#11493510)

You can try `text-shadow` property

```
text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px 1px;
```

Comment: That module is obsolete and has been replaced by http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts I'm not sure why they didn't leave a note at least.

Comment: Is that so? Hmm. What should one do if you want to make your font smoother?

Comment: @BoltClock: at the top of that working draft of 2002, is a link to the latest version.

Comment: @abhitalks: Oh, I see it now. So the two modules are one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because, it is non-standard:

> Though present in early (2002) drafts of CSS3 Fonts, font-smooth has
>   been removed from this specification and is currently not on the
>   standard track.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth