# Why is "Source Sans Pro" displaying at incorrect font-weight for "font-weight:200" in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm including Source Sans Pro from Google fonts and I realized that it's not displaying correctly in Google Chrome only, it seems.

I tried running an Incognito window just to make sure it wasn't a plug-in, and sure enough it's still showing at what seems to be `font weight 400` instead of `200` for ultra-light, even right on the Google Fonts site (as well as the project I caught the error in).

Is this a Chrome-only thing? It seems strange that Chrome wouldn't support that font at 200 font weight even on the Google Fonts site, hmm.

Heres an image from a screenshot of the google fonts page:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: The image does not correspond to what I see in Chrome 36 on Win 7: Extra-Light is very very light (bad for legibility really). Besides, you should show *your* code and explain exactly how it fails to work. The reference to weight 100 is very odd, unless it’s a typo; the font does not exist in that weight at all.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, i'll fix it. I'm on Chrome 36 on Win8 and the google fonts page. Yeah it's shown at 40pt font. I see that it was fixed with Chrome 37, thanks!

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Man, that's weird that you see it fine in Chrome 36. Oh and there was no code to show since this was straight from the Google Fonts page in an incognito window. I wonder if the Win8 + Chrome36 combination is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Status of the issue, June 2014: Fixed with Chrome 37

Well , chrome will use DirectWrite from version 37 and till that , most WD know that it dosen't renders fonts correctly.

Here its discussed : [Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692)

And another SO question with detailed answers : [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/is-there-any-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any news when Chrome 37 will be pushed out to everyone?

Comment: Right now with chrome 43 on Windows that problem occurs again.