# Chrome Text Flickr on using Css rotate. 'backface-visibility' making things worse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

Firstly, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/wytv7n7n/3/

I am using CSS rotate an icon on hover. I tried using 'webkit-backface-visibility: hidden' and '-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;'. They just make text thick and ugly.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="blog-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-E3B9ce7Ck20/UFBfFrkbV8I/AAAAAAAADX8/fFMHEyZcZDg/s400/Animated-Wallpapers.jpg">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- /.overlay -->
                    </div><!-- /.image -->
                    <h3>Welcome to A Safer World</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p>
            </div><!-- /.blog-item -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.blog-item{
overflow: hidden;
}
.image{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.image .overlay{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #49c8ff;
top: 0px;
opacity: 0;

transition:         all 400ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:    all 400ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition:      all 400ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:     all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.blog-item:hover .overlay{
opacity: 1;
}
.blog-item h3,
.blog-item p{
font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
font-weight: "400";   
 }
.overlay a{
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
border-radius: 100%;
top:30%;
text-align: center;

transition:         all 400ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:    all 400ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition:      all 400ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:     all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.image:hover a{
top: 40%;

-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.overlay a:hover{
background-color: #297595;
border: 1px solid #297595;
}
.overlay a i{
color: #fff;
position: relative;
top: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Turns out this flickering happens only on jsfiddle, my issue of text flickr was effecting other elements (http://timekill.in/test/with-backface/flickr.html). I did solve it by adding "overflow:hidden" for .image container. If you find out the solution for flickr on jsfiddle it would be great.

Comment: No that didn't solve my flickr problem. It was solved temporarily, it now appears.

Comment: Please explain with more description! When it flickers?

Comment: @Eirenaios: When I hover on the main div, plz check in the link:timekill.in/test/with-backface/flickr.html and the fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well , chrome will use DirectWrite from version 37 and till that , most WD know that it dosen't renders fonts correctly.

Here its discussed : [**Chromium issue**](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692)

And another SO question with detailed answers : [**SO link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/is-there-any-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome)

---

Try changing your font-family it solved by changing it to **sans-sarif** or
Try Other Fonts!

[FlickerRemoved](http://jsfiddle.net/wytv7n7n/5/)

```
.blog-item h3, .blog-item p {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400";

}
```