# Ragged website font on Windows

Tags: css, fonts, font-smoothing

I've been building this site for a while, however the font I use for headers looks ragged on Windows using Chrome, although it looks perfect on Mac or using Edge: [Link](http://claxio.com/villapegaso/cms.php?id=34)
I did try the various font smoothing properties to no avail and using text-shadow makes it look strange.
Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *Ragged*? Also provide screenshots of the difference, that would be really helpful. Is the font you are using is designed to be used in webpages? Please keep in mind that different OSes and browsers render font anti-aliasing differently

Comment: I might haves used the wrong term since English is not my first language, sorry. This is what I mean: http://imgur.com/OwX1lXz
Easier to see on a zoomed version: http://i.imgur.com/azGaPpf.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any "font smoothing" in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/is-there-any-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The font I use for headers looks ragged on Windows using Chrome

1. Your `webkit-font-smoothing` rule is missing a `-` prefix, it should be `-webkit-font-smoothing`
2. To solve the issue of Chrome font-rendering, add `-webkit-text-stroke: 0.3px;`

**Difference:**

[image: chrome font difference]

**Final code:**

```
h1, h2 {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.3px;
}
```

* You may need to apply the above CSS to all selectors that use the custom font.

---

**Preview**

[image: chrome font smoothing preview]

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11493510/877671
voting to close as duplicate.